# What was the first language with regexes?

Tags: programming

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), Regular Expressions (AKA *regexes*) have only been around since 1956:

> Regular expressions originated in 1956, when mathematician Stephen Cole Kleene described regular languages... Other early implementations of pattern matching include the SNOBOL language, which did not use regular expressions, but instead its own pattern matching constructs.
>
> Regular expressions entered popular use from 1968 in two uses: pattern matching in a text editor and lexical analysis in a compiler.

The description of SNOBOL's pattern matching abilities is vague: I'm not sure if they are actually able to match all regular languages. The article doesn't confirm if anything else came earlier either. I think that there must be something before regexes first became popular in 1968.

I really want to know what was the earliest regex flavor. And how does its syntax compare to "modern" regex syntax (PCRE, for example)?

---

Just to be clear, a regex flavor must be able to do the following things (just not necessarily with this syntax):

1. Concatenation

   - Match "cat" by stringing together three regexes: `c` + `a` + `t`
2. Union (AKA alternation)

   - Match either "c" or "d": `[cd]`
3. Star (AKA repetitions)

   - Match "cccccc": `c*`
4. Any combination of the above

   - Concatenation and Union
     Match either "cat" or "dog": `cat|dog`
   - Concatenation and Star
     Match "c"s followed by "d"s: `c*d*`
   - Union and Star
     Match any pattern of "c" and "d": `[cd]*`
   - All three
     Match any pattern of "cat" and "dog": `(cat|dog)*`

Comment: A SNOBOL manual is e.g. [here](http://www.snobol4.org/docs/burks/manual/contents.htm). It can also match e.g. balanced parenthesis, which regular expressions cannot, but doesn't really have alternation in tha form, so I'd say there's no real overlap with regular expressions.

Comment: grep and ed used regular expressions. They appear at least in Unix v4, so 1974. But I'm sure there were earlier uses ...

Comment: I feel that this question belongs on StackOverflow. This is really no different than _Which version of GCC contains feature X_.

Comment: @pipe [This is discussed on Meta](http://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/75). As a member of both sites, I asked here because (a) Stack Overflow might see it as a recommendation question, (b) I was certain the answer fell well within retro-land, (c) the question gets more visibility to experts here, and (d) this is a history question, not a specific programming question.

Comment: @dirkt SNOBOL's pattern matching capability far exceeded regular expressions (even today's regular expressions) as pattern matching was a _first class_ facility in the language: you could assign patterns to variables, then build pattern matching expressions up from smaller named expressions using recursion, indirection, and full control flow constructs including ifs and loops (built from SNOBOL's only control flow primitive: conditional goto). BTW, it did have an alternation operator `|` (just like regexp syntax) - see [here](http://berstis.com/s4ref/oper3i.htm).

Comment: I concur with the sentiment that SNOBOL patterns express more than regular expressions.  Plus, of course there's not that pesky confusion about whether ```*``` is supposed to represent the asterisk character or the pattern operation "zero or more instances", the latter being spelled ```ARBNO(pattern)```.

Answer (score 18):

I think I found it. It's called [COMIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMIT), and it dates back to 1957, just *one year* after Kleene's work was published. Wikipedia calls it the "first string processing language", so it fits the bill very nicely.

Wikipedia also says that its creation led to the creation of SNOBOL. After reading up on SNOBOL a bit, I realized it's actually pretty powerful too, capable of parsing Context-free grammars (CFGs).

[*An introduction to COMIT programming*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015040285333;view=1up;seq=13) is the best reference for the grammar that I've found so far. Keep in mind, it's an ENTIRE programming language. I am sure it's possible to do all of the things I mentioned; the language is Turing-complete, but it [seems](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/T87-1009) like it is geared towards non-recursive parsing.

The syntaxes for the "patterns" and the "strings" are a little weird (but mutually similar), so I doubt that modern regex syntax was derived from it.

(The oldest regex flavor with syntax like modern regexes that I know of are Unix utilities, as dirkt mentioned: grep, ed, sed, awk. This could be an entirely different question to ask about.)

Characters can be grouped together into arbitrary groups called *constituents*, which are separated by plus signs. Ironically, my initial example of concatenation is *exactly* how it looks:

```
C + A + T
```

It can also be written as one constituent:

```
CAT
```

To include a space, the dash (`-`) character is used:

```
THE + -CAT
```

Or, as a single constituent:

```
THE-CAT
```

Strings are stored in memory called the *workspace*. "Rules" are matched against the workspace, and replacements can be made.

It's pretty easy to do a replacement, actually. To change `THE-CAT` into `THE-DOG`, you could use this rule:

```
* CAT = DOG *
```

Deletion is easy too. To remove `THE-` from `THE-DOG`, you could use this rule:

```
* THE- = 0 *
```

If you have `DOG` and wanted to double the `G`, you could use numbers. Numbers are meta characters, as my deletion example shows you. Ignoring `0`, they have a similar meaning to modern capture groups, if you imagine each constituent as a capture group. For example, `G` could be doubled by using the following rule:

```
* G = 1 + 1 *
```

(No, one plus one isn't two, it's `GG`!)

Moving onto more complex constructs, `$` is essentially equivalent to the modern `.*`. On the other hand, in order to do something similar to the modern `.{3}` (three characters), you would use `$3` in COMIT (assuming each constituent was a character, I think).

If you had `THE-CAT + , + -WHO-WISHED + -IT-WAS + -A-DOG + , + -BARKED` and you wanted to remove everything between the commas, you would use:

```
* , + $ + , = 0 *
```

---

Like I said, there's a whole lot more past this. It has some type of GOTO, but I don't have any experience with using GOTOs (I come from an era where GOTO is something to be avoided, not taught).

It also might help me if I had a way to run this stuff. I guess I'll have to write up a flowchart instead or something `:)` <sup><sub>Edit: Just remembered [this site](https://regexper.com/#%3C%5B%5E%3E%5D%2B%3E) gives me flowcharts automatically from regexes... No paper needed</sub></sup> .

Comment: I browsed the manual, and it doesn't look like a full regular expression to me. What's missing is the ability to compose the primitives arbitrarily, e.g. to have something like (a(b(ab|c)*|a)b)*. What's also missing is the correspondence to finite automata, and compilation to what's basically a table for the automaton. So I don't think it counts. :-)

Comment: @dirkt I encourage you to read [*Machine methods for proving logical arguments expressed in English*](http://mt-archive.info/MT-1965-Darlington.pdf). Let the language speak for itself if you aren't convinced by me. :)

Comment: Still not convinced. That looks like they are using a set of COMAL rules to implement a [term rewriting system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting#Term_rewriting_systems). Term rewriting systems can implement type-0 (unrestricted) grammars, which are provably distinct from type-3 (regular) grammars, but that doesn't make the rules themselves regular expressions (which is what you were looking for, if I understood your question correctly). Yes, you also can write down type-3 grammars this way. But regular expressions as in grep are used very differently.

Comment: @dirkt I have very little knowledge about the the computer science side of things, but from what I understand, type 0 is a superset of all the other types. [Relevant material](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/6266). I originally considered mentioning BNF in my Q but decided against it. That being said, I think that there is more than one answer to this question; COMIT is not the ancestor of regex syntax nor implementation.

Comment: If you don't know the CS part: The selling point of regular expressions is that they have a comparatively cheap implementation as finite automatons, and one of the forms to describe them is a single expression as compared to a complete grammar with several rules (BNF etc.). That's why you can conveniently use them from the commandline in programs like grep, and a PDP-11 has enough memory to make that work. On the IBM 701 where COMIT was developed this wouldn't have worked, so COMIT does repeated transformations on a smallish buffer, which is slower, but more general.

Comment: If you rephrase your question to "what are early implementations of formal language theory results", then COMIT is a very good answer, and I really appreciate you digging it up because I didn't know about it. :-) But it really doesn't have any connection with the class of regular expressions and their implementation as used in grep.

Answer (score 7):

*(Note: This answer is pretty seriously TLDR, but I needed to work
through the following analysis of the paper in order to confirm my
understanding of FLIP; the paper itself is not terribly clear, IMHO.
If you think that the analysis should be removed, let me know in a
comment, but I have no better home for this right now.)*

The first appearance of regular expressions as we know them now
(`[abc].*def` etc.) appears to have been Ken Thompson's implementation
of them in the QED editor in 1967. In the following I'll call these
"Thompson regexps."

Daniel G. Bobrow's April 1966 paper ["Format-directed List Processing
in LISP"](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/633242.pdf) describes a pattern matching and replacment language
called "FLIP" that is embedded in LISP using patterns and formats that
are "greatly generalized versions of the left-half and right-half
rules of COMIT and SNOBOL." (FLIP was implemented in LISP 1.5.) While
the matching and replacement applies to lists of characters, these are
clearly isomorphic to strings of charcters: `"ABC"` is expressed as
`(A B C)` here. However, FLIP can also deal with deeper structure
within these lists, such as `(A (B C) D)`, as we shall see.

Unlike [COMIT](http://www.mt-archive.info/MT-1958-Yngve.pdf) or SNOBOL, FLIP is in the following ways very much the
modern concept of Thompson regexps in modern programming languages:

1. The pattern matching language is embedded in a general-purpose
   programming language (unlike COMIT or SNOBOL); patterns are
   executed by passing to a *match* function the pattern and a target
   list against which to match it.
2. The pattern language is similar (although differing in surface
   syntax) to Thompson regexps, though also offering more powerful
   facilities for subtitution of variables, composition, etc.
   (Substitution of variables and the like is also available via host
   programming language facilities in modern programming languages,
   consider the Python code `pat = re.compile('Hello, ' + name)`; FLIP
   also uses the host language to aid in this.)

FLIP patterns are not, however, compiled to a finite-state automaton,
as Thompson regexps are, in part because they're more general.
(Arbitrary LISP functions can be included in the pattern matching
language both to produce pattern fragments and to modify how the
pattern matches the target.) They can, however, be translated from the
"external" notation used here to a more efficient internal format.

Further, FLIP patterns are also more general in that they can deal
with nested lists, matching *structures* within them, as mentioned
above and described in more detail below. (According to the paper,
"COMIT has lists only to depth 3 and SNOBOL and AXLE deal only with
linear strings.")

### FLIP Description

The following is my summary of the relevant parts of the paper, as
best I understand it. The order here is not ideal since I'm closely
following the paper, which seems to jump around a bit in its
introduction of various concepts.

FLIP uses two functions, *match* and *construct* to match patterns in
lists and reconstruct lists based on a format, respectively. Here I'll
deal only with the former, as it's not clear to me if you were also
asking about formatting of replacement strings.

*match* takes two arguments, a list to be parsed and a pattern to
match, and returns a parsing of the list with respect to that pattern
if it matches the pattern. (This parsed representation can later be
passed to *construct*.)

#### Basic Constant and Pattern Matching

The first matching constructs described in the paper are:

```
FLIP    regexp  meaning
------------------------------------------------------------------
x       x       match constant element x
$       .*      match anything, including zero-length sequence
$n      .{n}    match a segment of length n
```

The first example (aligned by me for convenience in reading, and
equivalant regexp added by me):

```
Regexp:      .*    .{3}    A   .*      .   B   .*
Pattern:    ($     $3      A   $       $1  B   $  )
List:       (A W   X Y Z   A   B C D   E   B   C D)
Parse:      [A W] [X Y Z] [A] [B D C] [E] [B] [C D]
```

The next example shows how both variables can be used and sublists can
be matched. Given a binding of `A` to list `(X Y Z)` we can match that
list as a sublist within the list we're parsing:

```
Pattern:    ($         (=A)      $)
List:       (A X Y Z   (X Y Z)   Q)
Parse:      [A X Y Z] [(X Y Z)] [Q])
```

`=` is actually an evaluation operator, so arbitrary LISP expressions
and functions can be called for the value that will be matched.

The `**` operator treats the expression to which it is applied not as
a sublist but as a segment of the main list. So we can match the
`X Y Z` segment within the main list, rather than the subsequent
`(X Y Z)` sublist, with:

```
Pattern:    ($  (** (=A))  $)
List:       (A   X Y Z     (X Y Z) Q)
Parse:      [A] [X Y Z]   [(X Y Z) Q])
```

The `*` operator treats the expression to which it's applied as a
single item, i.e., the standalone `(=A)` in the earlier example is
really `(* (=A))`; the translator inserted `*` by default because it's
a common use case.

Sublists can also be matched with constants:

```
Pattern:    ($           ($   F $)   $)
List:       (A (B C) D   (B E F  )   G)
Parse:      [A (B C) D] [(B E F  )] [G]
```

The parse there is actually the "top-level" parsing; parsing of the
nested pattern is also done, meaning that `[B E] [F] []` is also
somehow in the output parse. (The paper doesn't go into the details of
the parse representation.)

The expressions in the example above produced constants to be matched
(e.g., `=A` matched the constant `(X Y Z)`), but it's also possible to
have expressions produce *patterns* to be matched. For this the `*`
and `**` operators have corresponding `$*` and `$**` operators. Thus
one could set `A` to `($ F $)` and `($ ($* (=A)) $)` would be the same
pattern as given in the example above.

#### Alternation and Repetition

The paper now moves on to the remaining missing bits from the requirements
in the question: alternation and repetitions.

Alternation is expressed with the `EITHER` function which takes a list
of the alternates to match:

```
  digit = ( (EITHER (1) (2) (3) (4) (5) (6) (7) (8) (9)) )
integer = ( (EITHER (=digit) (($** (=digit)) ($** (=integer)))) )
```

(I corrected the parens for the definition of `integer`; the
right-hand side appears to be cut off in the paper.)

`digit` matches any digit from 1 to 9. (Don't ask why 0 was left out.
It's just that kind of paper.) `integer` matches a single digit or a
single digit followed by an `integer`, i.e. a list of digits of any
length. Note the use of `$**` here to ensure that the value returned
by `(=digit)` or `(=integer)` is interpreted as a *pattern*, rather
than a constant list. This would be used in a top-level expression
just as it is internally, with `($** (=integer))` to match a sequence
of digits within a list.

Repetition is expressed with `(REPEAT p)` which matches zero or more
occurrences of pattern *p*, or `(REPEAT n p)` which matches *n* or
more occurances of *p*. A sequence of patterns *p q ...* may be also
be given in which case `REPEAT` matches zero or more (*n* or more)
segments matching that sequence. Examples:

- `((REPEAT $2))` would match a list only if it had an even number of
  items. (Note the lack of `$` before and after the `(REPEAT $2)`,
  leaving that expression anchored to the beginning and end of the
  list it's attempting to match.)
- `((REPEAT 1 (=digit)))` would match a list consisting of one or more
  digits, as with `(($** (=integer)))` above.
- `(REPEAT A $1 B)` would match `(A X B  A Y B  A Z B)`.

(Presumably `EITHER` and `REPEAT` produce parse output with the
details of the matches in the same way as given in the initial
Pattern/List/Parse examples; that's not described in this paper.)

At this point Bobrow points out that FLIP can directly express regular
expressions:

> The EITHER and REPEAT subpatterns are similar to the operations of
>   disjunction, "v" and * in the formation of regular expressions. In
>   fact, given the definition of a regular expression, it is very easy
>   to write the FLIP matching pattern which will parse a string if, and
>   only if, it is an example of that regular expression. For example,
>   the pattern
>
> ```
>   (REPEAT (EITHER (A B) ((REPEAT (EITHER (B C) (D E F)) )) ))
> ```
>
> will be equivalent to the regular expression
>
> ```
>   (A B v (B C v D E F) * ) *
> ```
>
> and will match with
>
> ```
>   A B D E F B C B C D E F A B.
> ```

#### Further Notes

The paper goes on to say that "the operation of the match is a
sequential, left to right process." Thus, matching `($ C $)` against
`(A B C D C D E)` will result in the parse `[A B] [C] [D C D E]`, not
`[A B C D] [C] [D E]`.

Because of this left-to-right process, back-matches are available.
Each "elementary pattern" is assigned a numerical mark corresponding
to its position in the total pattern (sort of an automatic version of
Thompson regexp grouping with `\(` and `\)`): in `($ $2 A $)` mark 2
references whatever `$2` matched and mark 3 references the `A` match.
This can be referenced with a number; e.g., to match two repeated
items in a list:

```
Pattern:    ($   $2    $     2     $)
List:       (A   B C   D E   B C   D)
Parse:      [A] [B C] [D E] [B C] [D]
```

(Note that the 2 in `$2` refers just to two items, and is no relation
to the later `2` referring to the second item in the pattern list. I
think this example could be better written, but I didn't want to
change what the paper gave.)

Items can be named using the `NAME` operator, e.g.
`($ (NAME FOO $2) A $)` will assign to variable `FOO` whatever was
matched by `$2`.

There's a lot more functionality and notation for marks, such as
describing segments of subpatterns, little of which is discussed in
the paper.

Particularly powerful is the ability to attach predecates to patterns
which can take previously matched segments as arguments.

```
Pattern:    ($3      $3 / (EQUAL (=REVERSE 1)) )
List:       (A B C   C B A)
Parse:      [A B C] [C B A]
```

There are also optimizations available because full information about
the parse is kept. The paper mentions that `($1 $ 1 $5 $)`, which
matches any target list where the first item is repeated at least five
times before the end of the target list, can involve continuing to try
matches when there's no possibility of the pattern actually matching.
Attaching a special failure predeciate to `$` can optimize this,
though the paper doesn't give the details.

There is also a method of doing a reverse (right-to-left) search,
`$R`, which can be convenient in certain situations.

#### Conclusion

There's even more before the paper gets on to the *construct* process,
but I think what we've got to this point makes it pretty clear that
FLIP is indeed a (particularly powerful) implementation of matching
that can do everything done with regular expressions in programs as we
know them today.

Comment: Very nice answer - though I disagree with your brief dismissal of COMIT as an acceptable (and earlier!) language with REs.

Comment: @davidbak Fair enough. I suppose one thing I was personally focused on, to the detriment of the question perhaps, was the modern idea of a regex being just part of a general purpose language, rather than the core of a language that was not suitable for non-text-processing uses, as with Perl vs. `sed`. In fact, LISP with FLIP might have very much the same relationship to COMIT as Perl does to `sed`.

Comment: You could be right and I very much wish I had known about FLIP - which I only learned about here! - back in the day when I was working with LISP.  But TBH I have long preferred the SNOBOL/SPITBOL/Icon family of languages when working with strings: pattern matching turned up to 11!

Comment: @davidbak I think if you would post an answer here about your personal experience with COMIT and SNOBOL, explaining how they map to `sed`/`awk`/Perl/etc.-type regex use, that would be incredibly valuable. So far, we don't have any answers from anyone who's actually used these earlier languages in any serious way. And from a quick scan of the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNOBOL) it seems that SNOBOL was probably more general-purpose than I'd originally thought.